# In LINUX determine if a .a library/archive 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: linux, 32bit-64bit, archive

We distribute in Linux a static lib in both 64-bit and 32-bit versions.  When troubleshooting a customer, I would like my diagnostic shell script to quickly eliminate the issue by checking the .a archive file to detetmine whether it is 32 or 64 bit.  The methods that occur to me are less than elegant:

1. extract a .o member and ask the "file" command (e.g., ELF 32-bit etc)
2. start including a dummy member coded to indicate, e.g. 32bit.o/64bit.o and use "ar -t" to check

I have tried "strings xyz.a | grep 32" but this doesn't work well over versions.  Not a heartbreaker problem, but if you know of an elegant solution, I would like to know.

Comment: I know about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184502/on-a-unix-linux-system-how-can-i-learn-more-about-a-mylib-a-archive , looking for a better soln.

Comment: The solution in the other question seems to address the problem quite neatly, but a quick way is nm foo.a | grep '^0' | head -1 | wc -c - if the result is 17 (16+1 == 8bytes + 1 char for line return), it's 64bit, if it's 9 it's 32bit (8+1 == 4bytes + 1 char for line return)

Comment: What if I get 14? o_0

Answer (score 129):

`objdump` seems like the best way:

```
objdump -f libfoo.a | grep ^architecture
```

Comment: `file` is easier to read as stated below http://stackoverflow.com/a/8909086/233906

Comment: I get `architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000039:`.. does it mean that it's both..? that's unlikely. please help :D

Comment: @Paladin: That's 64 bit - the x86 architectures are described by objdump as `i386` (plain old IA32), `i386:x86-64` (AMD64) and `i386:x64-32` (the X32 32-bit-address-space-in-long-mode architecture).

Comment: @caf Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The flag '-f' in 'objdump' specifies to display the contents of the overall file header of the library 'libfoo.a'. This output from 'objdump' is then piped into the grep command which searches for the word 'architecture'. The character '^' signifies that 'architecture' should begin the line.

Comment: Clean it up and remove dupes: `objdump -f lib.a | grep ^architecture | cut -d' ' -f-2 | sort -u` :)

Answer (score 40):

The simplest way is to use the file command.

```
$ file <.so file or .a file>
```

Comment: in the msys environment this simply echos *<file>: current ar archive*, not the target architecture.

Comment: Likewise in my current Linux (Ubuntu) environment.

Comment: likewise in centos7

Comment: It works fine on Ubuntu 16.04.  
(1) `file armeabi/libpique.so` --> `libpique.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker, stripped`.  
(2) `file x86/libpique.so` --> `libpique.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped`

Comment: A .so file and a .a file are not the same thing. Showing that this works for a shared library is not the same as showing that it works with a static library. The original question is about a static library (.a file). In my case (using MSYS) the objdump solution posted by caf works where using file just prints 'ar archive' the same as scones gets.

Answer (score 17):

Just use the file command; i.e. `file library.so`

Comment: The question is specifically for static libraries.

Answer (score 5):

> oops, that missing sed means that it was displaying to many items.

Just in an answer:

```
count=$(nm foo.a | grep '^0' | head -1 | sed 's/ .*//' | wc -c)
((count == 17)) && echo 64bit
((count == 9)) && echo 32bit
((count == 0)) && echo '??bit'
```

How it's supposed to work:

- nm - get the symbols from the library
- grep - get lines starting with a hex string (address of symbol in file)
- head - get the first line
- sed - remove everything past the whitespace, including the whitespace
- wc - count the number of characters.

In a 32 bit environment, you get addresses made up of 8 hex digits, adding the new line gives you `9`, In a 64bit environment, you get addresses made up of 16 hex digits, adding the new line gives you `17`.

Comment: Might want to throw a sed -e 's/ .*//' in there

Comment: I get 73 by the way. 
Care to explain why it should work?

Comment: oops, that missing sed was important. Answer updated, with an explanation of how it's supposed to work

Answer (score 1):

If there are functions that are specific to a particular version you could try nm then grep for the function.

Comment: You might be able to write some code that looks for specific bytes in the library. You could try using od on both files and finding differences between the two.

Comment: Another solution would be to rename the libraries.